# How do I set a suggested file name using JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(...)?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

The `JFileChooser` seems to be missing a feature: a way to suggest the file name when saving a file (the thing that usually gets selected so that it would get replaced when the user starts typing).

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to use the `setSelectedFile` method.

```
JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
jFileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("fileToSave.txt"));
jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(parent);
```

The file doesn't need to exist.

If you pass a File with an absolute path, `JFileChooser` will try to position itself in that directory (if it exists).

Comment: However, if you're in `DIRECTORIES_ONLY` mode, then this doesn't work. I don't see a way to set the default name of a new directory.

Answer (score 4):

setSelectedFile doesn't work with directories as mentioned above, a solution is

```
try {
    FileChooserUI fcUi = fileChooser.getUI();
    fcUi.setSelectedFile(defaultDir);
    Class<? extends FileChooserUI> fcClass = fcUi.getClass();
    Method setFileName = fcClass.getMethod("setFileName", String.class);
    setFileName.invoke(fcUi, defaultDir.getName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately, `setFileName` is not included in the UI interface, thus the need to call it dynamically. Only tested on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If that doesn't work, here is a workaround:

```
dialog.getUI().setFileName( name )
```

But you should check whether the selection mode is `FILES_ONLY` or `FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES`. If it's `DIRECTORIES_ONLY`, then `setSelectedFile()` will strip the file name.

Comment: How would you access the dialog though? It's private, created on the spot in `showSaveDialog()`, and disposed immediately after it was shown, still inside that function.