# JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(…) - preserve suggested file name after changing directory

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

There are already some questions about how to set a [default file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name) for a JFileChooser control.

I'm having a few problems with **preserving that default filename when switching directories**.
Right now, when I do that, the original filename I supplied get over overwritten by the path of the new directory itself.

Is there anything can be done in order to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a PropertyListener to the file chooser, and if you get a "directoryChanged" property, set your default file again.

For example:

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener() {
      public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent evt )
      {
        if ( evt.getPropertyName().equals( "directoryChanged" ) )
        {
          JFileChooser me = (JFileChooser)evt.getSource(); 
          me.setSelectedFile( new File( "text.txt" ) );
        }
      }
    });
```

It seems like it might do what you want, but is more a workaround than a proper solution.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on Windows 7.
When I execute that code, the filename field is not updated with the filename I supply, although the corresponding PropertyChangeEvent (JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY) is fired.

Comment: I was using Vista with default look and feel. What L&F are you using?

Comment: Hey abahgat, I tried this out with System and Nimbus L&F on Vista and it works OK, so yeah - most likely a win7 thing as you suggest rather than a L&F thing. I will have access to a Windows 7 box on Thursday to try it out, but if you get it solved before then please post a comment or something.

Comment: I made a few more tests today, and I actually figured out what is preventing your solution from working.

I was calling fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES), and it didn't work because of that.

Thank you.