# JasperViewer: How to set filename while saving report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am creating Java desktop application. I am using [DynamicReports API](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/) to create report.

The report was viewed in a *JasperViewer*. When I click save button, I want to display a name for report to save by default. How to set name for the report by default?

Comment: You can read [Specifying default file name in JasperViewer](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=56803) post on [jasperforge.org](http://jasperforge.org)

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to import the package  `com.jasperassistant.designer.viewer.ViewerComposite`
so on that viewer composite you can see a save icon on you left top corner. you can provide any name and location where you want to save. i think that the good way of saving report through your jasper report.

Comment: i think you misunderstand my question.sorry for my english. i already have save option in the top left corner and it works properly but i want a default name for the report in the filename field in the save window.actually  the filename field was empty  and file format was "JRPrint" by default. i want to change this default value. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Then i think that you have to change in `JFileChooser` instead of looking into `API`.
You can give default name to be displayed.

This way the approach would be:

```
JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
jFileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("fileToSave.txt"));
jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(parent);
```

And If you pass a File with an absolute path, `JFileChooser` will try to position itself in that directory (if it exists).

I got this source from [following place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name)