# How to set a default file name to Swing JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

I want to set a default file name as `Untitled.txt` in text-box of this `JFileChooser`. Can I set this?

Comment: Hi Chirag Soni, [take a look at this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/335497/GUI/java/Setting-default-name-JFileChooser) If you already have a code, please post code snippet :) [References from our site StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Setting+default+name+in+JFileChooser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(...) - how to set suggested file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        File file = new File("C:/untitled.txt");
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(file);
```

You have to specify the complete path to `untitled.txt`

Comment: `C:/` How would that work on Linux/Unix or OS X?  Better to point the user towards `user.home`.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the setSelectedFile method and pass a file as a parameter. The file doens't have to exist. 

If the path to the file is specified the file chooser will try to point to the file directory if it exists

`JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("C:\\file.txt"));
fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);`