# JFileChooser Save Dialog Suggest File Name

Tags: java, swing, filenames, jfilechooser, savefiledialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(…) - how to set suggested file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name)

I have seen this question asked a few times but no answer has been any help to me. I want the save dialog to suggest a file name like "myFile.txt" using JFileChooser.

Heres what i have:

```
JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
jFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:\\"));
jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
```

Comment: And this does not work? 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name

Comment: Apologies, never came across those somehow. I even went through the suggestions while typing this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do it:

```
jFileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File(optionalPath + "myFile.txt"));
```