# Clear selected file form JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to unselect the file from `JFileChooser`, when i click some button. 
For example, if i click "Reset" button, the selected file from `JFileChooser` will be unselect.

Here's the code of my `JFileChooser`:

```
 public void fileChoose(){
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user","home")));
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg", "png");
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

And here the Reset button code :

```
private void clearAllField(){
    nik_input.setText("");
    name_input.setText("");
    born_input.setText("");
    birth_date_input.setDate(null);
    gender_input.setSelectedIndex(0);
    address_input.setText("");
    job_input.setText("");
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are many problems with your code. You configure the dialog after you show it (change the order so showOpenDialog() is the last before chooser.getSelectedFile()). Your create a filter but you aren't setting it in the File Chooser.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to clear the file of the JFileChooser, you reset the string you have in your class (and the representation of it, normally in a JLabel). And you should reuse the file chooser.

If you don't reset and don't recreate it each time, the user will have the same directory opened which is usually a good UX.

A simple example could be as follow:

```
public class Foo {

  JFileChooser chooser;
  String path;

  public Foo() {
    this.chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user","home")));
    // TODO Other file chooser configuration...
    path = "";
  }

  public void fileChoose(){

    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    this.path = file.getAbsolutePath();

  }

  public String getPath() {
    return this.path;
  }

  public String resetPath() {
    this.path = "";
  }

}
```

If for whatever reason you want to change the selected file in the JFileChooser see [JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(...) - how to set suggested file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name).

And also take a look at the official tutorial in [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

---

See my comments about other problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File(""));
```

Works for me with Java 1.6 and above.