# How to pass file name as parameter to JFilechooser file name text-field?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser

how to pass a file name as a parameter to JFilechooser file name text-field?
I am trying to pass a filename as a parameter using table select row filename path to jFilechooser File
Name but I don't know how to do that?

Here is my Code:

```java
JFrame parentFrame = new JFrame();
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");
int userSelection = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);


if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File fileToSave = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
}
```

Here is the project image:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JFileChooser.showSaveDialog(...) - how to set suggested file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356671/jfilechooser-showsavedialog-how-to-set-suggested-file-name)

Comment: Yes perfect it's work thanks a lot.